# Simple explanation for UNION

Tags: sql, union

What is the meaning (result) of this SQL statement in layman's term?:

```
SELECT mainTable.Year FROM mainTable 
UNION SELECT mainTable.Title FROM mainTable
```

Comment: Show results from both `SELECT`s and remove the duplicates.

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html (or the documentation for your SQL vendor)

Comment: The meaning of this query is nonsense since a Year is not a Title ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In set theory

if `A={1,2,3}` and `B={2,3,4,5}` then `A union B={1,2,3,4,5}`  `-- No duplicates here!`

where as `A union all B={1,2,3,2,3,4,5}` `--with duplicates`

similarly in `sql`

its written like

```
select * from A
union  -- or union all
select * from B
```

[SEE HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29)

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to check Wikipedia!

Answer (score 1):

The `UNION` combines two results.

When you have two `SELECT` statements, all of them has a result. If those results contain equivalent number of columns (and those - the ones which are at the same position - column's datatypes are equal or compatible with eachother), you can get those results combined into one result.

The `UNION` will filter out the duplications. You can use `UNION ALL` to prevent filtering.

See this SQLFiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42569/2